# Need SQL query for sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gurus,
I have data like as below

```
Id  Stage   Name    Stage1dt    stage2dt    stage1amt   stage2amt
1     A     tst1    23-01-2015  01-12-2015  100         200
2     B     tst2    23-02-2015  02-12-2015  2323        232
3     A     tsr2    25-01-2015  null        200         400
```

I need SQL that will give stage wise count and sum corresponding stage amount for given month. For example if i give month as Jan (1)... I need output like below.. Pls help

```
        A    B
Count   2    1
Amount  300  200
```

query some thing like this..

```
(Select count(1) from tbl where stage = 'A' and month(stage1dt) = @month) Acount,

(select count(1) from tbl where stage = 'B'  and month(stage2dt) = @month)  BCount,
```

Comment: Correlated sub-querys in the select list, where you sum until current row's end of month.

Comment: i have written subqueries for each column like mentioned part of question .. i want to kno i that rite way

Comment: Please explain the logic.  What do the values in the `b` column mean?  The one data row doesn't have any january ates.

Comment: this is a table that has various products at various stages... stgdt column indicates when the product came to that stage...need stage wise count and amount for given month parameter

Comment: Where did you get B Amount 200 from?

Comment: How the `B` amount calculated as 200 ??

Comment: Your comment didn't clarified anything. Can you comment with more details?

Comment: Each stage has its own stage column and amount column.. as i have mentioned... Stage1dt,stage1amt for first stage (A) and stage2dt,stage2amt for second stage (B)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this?

```
Declare @Month varchar(20)
Set @Month = 'February'

Select 'Count', A, B From

(Select Stage, Count(Stage) stgamt
From tbl
where DateName(Month,case Stage when 'A' then Stgdt1 when 'B' then Stgdt2 end) = @Month
Group By Stage) as s
PIVOT
(SUM(Stgamt) for Stage in (A, B)) as piv

UNION

Select 'Amount', A, B From

(Select Stage, Case Stage when 'A' then Sum(amt1) when 'B' then Sum(amt2) end as Amount
From tbl
where DateName(Month,case Stage when 'A' then Stgdt1 when 'B' then Stgdt2 end) = @Month
Group By Stage) as s
PIVOT
(SUM(Amount) for Stage in (A, B)) as piv
```

Change DateName to Month if you just want to enter the month as an int

Comment: it is not that simple... Each stage has its own stagecolumn and amount column.. as i have mentioned... Stage1dt for first stage and stage2dt for second stage...

Comment: @Saravanan So Stage B only uses Stgdt2 and Stage A only uses Stgdt1?

Comment: rite.. same goes for amount column too..

Comment: @Saravanan how about the edited? It will look at Date2 for B and Date1 for A and same goes for the amounts.

Comment: it gives data but How I can pivot this data, like all stages on columns and count and amount as rows

Comment: @Saravanan Try the edited. You have to perform a Union on two pivot tables to achieve what you're after but this should work.